# Click dispatch not working with Jquery and Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

bit of a variation on a question I've asked before but the issue is this. We want to show a cart dropdown on the click of an 'add to cart' button. The issue is that knockout and jquery don't seem to be playing nice together with the click dispatch because when you click the button, something seems to prevent the drop down from showing. I am sure I am doing something wrong. Here's the code. I've spent way too much time on this and about to throw my computer :). It works if you just do the event on the console (of course).

HTML for the button and cart that needs to be shown

```
        <a href="#" class="button product-add-to-cart" data-bind="click:$root.addProductToCart.bind($data)">Add to Cart</a>
        <a href="#" class="button purple product-more-info" data-bind="click:$root.productShowMoreInfo.bind($data)">More Info</a>

         <li id="cart-nav" class="nav-menu cart">
           <a class="first" href="#">
             Cart (<span data-bind="text:cartTotalItems">19</span>)
              <div class="caret">
               <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
           </a>
        </li>
```

JS

```
  self.addProductToCart = function(data, event) {
    var $productNotification = $(event.target).prev().children('.product-notification');
    ax.Cart.addCartItem({product_id:data.id, name:data.name, description:data.description});
    self.openCartMenu();
    $productNotification.addClass('rise');
    $productNotification.on('animationend',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('rise');
});};

   self.openCartMenu = function () {
    $('#cart-nav').find('a.first').click();};
```

Comment: There's no dropdown in your code. Please try to make a [mcve], there's currently both quite some bit of code missing to repro the problem, as well as some code probably irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: On a side note, I strongly recommend against mixing jQuery and KnockoutJS like that. Just about all jQuery code in your example has a KnockoutJS mvvm-style equivalent which will work much better. E.g. don't call `removeClass` but instead modify your view model state and use a `class` binding instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will try to implement via KO.